# Reading InputStream's header question

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm trying to read the header of an `InputStream` file. Every header info contains information. However, I have trouble to understand the process of reading the header.

For example, I have:

```
InputStream sourceFile = //.... stuff.
sourceFile.read() | (sourceFile.read() << 8) | (sourceFile.read() << 16) 
      | (sourceFile.read() << 24)
```

from an example code.

Why don't I just use `sourceFile.read()` once? What does the single `|` means and what does `<< number` in this particular context mean?

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: What does 'header' mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read()` returns `int`, but it reads one byte from the file, so the idea is to get the first 4 bytes and convert them to a 32-bit int (while changing their [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).

The operators you refer to are binary and bitwise operators. please refer [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! But why does big-endian mean, and why 4 bytes? There are number like 8, 16 and 24, but what comes the 4 from?

Comment: The first one (`sourceFile.read()`) is a shift of 0 :). please read from the links I gave you.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're getting terms a bit confused here - the header is the first part of a file but the inputstream is just the stream used to read from that file. There's no "InputStream file". Headers are also different for each file - there's no standard "header format" for all files.

What it seems this particular piece of code is doing is reading the first 32 bit integer from the file (the multiple reads are needed because each read() call just reads one byte.)

In terms of the <<, that's a left shift operator, and the number after it determines the number of bits to shift along. The numbers increase from 8 to 16 to 24 because the bits are being shifted to their correct position (8 bits in a byte, so the number to shift increases by 8 each time.)